# GridView Sample in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I need GridView Sample to bind image and text data to item template.Anyone please tell me samples on that ,how to bind the data to gridview in windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

[XAML ListView and GridView essentials sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListViewSimple-d5fc27dd)